# ConcurrentQueue .Net: Multithreaded consumer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrent-queue

I had a very basic question which is more around concepts of `ConcurrentQueue`. A queue is FIFO. When multiple threads start accessing it, how do we guarantee FIFO?
Suppose, I have added `Apple`, `Oranges`, `Lemon`, `Peach` and `Apricot` - in that order. The first `TryTake` should return `Apple`. But what happens when multiple threads starts giving their own `TryTake` requests? Would'nt there be a possibility that when one thread could return `Lemon` even before another thread could return `Apple`? I am assuming the other items will also be returned till the Queue is empty. But will these returns govern around the basic principles of FIFO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior of the the `ConcurrentQueue` itself is always going to be FIFO.

When we talk about threads "returning" items from the `ConcurrentQueue`, we're talking about an operation that involves both dequeuing an item *and* performing some sort of an operation that enables you to observe what has been dequeued. Whether it's printing an output or adding that item to another list, you don't actually know which item has been taken out of the queue until you inspect it.

While the queue itself is FIFO, you can't predict the sequence in which those other events, such as inspecting the dequeued items, will occur. The items will be dequeued FIFO, but you may or may not be able to observe what comes out of the queue in that order. The different threads may not perform that inspection or output in exactly the same order in which they removed items from the queue.

In other words, it's going to happen FIFO but it may or may not always look like it. You wouldn't want to read from a `ConcurrentQueue` concurrently if the exact sequence in which the items handled was critical.

If you were to test this (I'm about to write something) then you'd probably find items getting processed in exact FIFO sequence most of the time, but then every once in a while they wouldn't be.

---

Here's a console app. It's going to

- insert the numbers from 1-5000 in a `ConcurrentQueue`, single-threaded.
- perform concurrent operations to dequeue each of those items and move them to another `ConcurrentQueue`. **This is the "multithreaded consumer."**
- Read the items in the second queue (single threaded, again) and report any numbers that are out of sequence.

Many times I run it and nothing is out of sequence. But about 50% of the time it reports just a few numbers out of sequence. So if you were counting on all of the numbers getting processed in their original sequence it would happen with almost all of the numbers most of the time. But then it wouldn't. That's fine if you don't care about the exact sequence, but buggy and unpredictable if you do.

The conclusion - don't depend on the exact sequence of multithreaded operations.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConcurrentQueueExperiment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
            var outputQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
            Enumerable.Range(1,5000).ToList().ForEach(inputQueue.Enqueue);
            while (inputQueue.Any())
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    int dequeued;
                    if (inputQueue.TryDequeue(out dequeued))
                    {
                        outputQueue.Enqueue(dequeued);
                    }
                });
            }
            int output = 0;
            var previous = 0;
            while (outputQueue.TryDequeue(out output))
            {
                if(output!=previous+1)
                    Console.WriteLine("Out of sequence: {0}, {1}", previous, output);
                previous = output;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, especially for "The items will be dequeued FIFO, but you may or may not be able to observe what comes out of the queue in that order."

Comment: Many thanks. That definitely helps answer. However, if its always FIFO how does multi-threading help then? I might as well `TryTake` sequentially if that's how multi-threading would also "report" the items? Any benefits of multi-threading if it cant take out simultaneously any item and just needs to take out the first item (I know that defeats the purpose of Queue but surely multi-threading and dequeueing sequentially is not going hand-in-hand?)

Comment: I just checked Scott's code and remove the TPL calls to dequeue and made it sequential. There is a huge performance saving. While with TPL, dequeue takes almost 1000 ms for 50K items in an i7, quad core, 16 GB machine, if I do the dequeue sequential, I am getting it within 23-30 ms average. So is multi-threading of concurrent queue a bottleneck since the items will anyways be retrieved FIFO. This comes back again the previous question I was seeking help on - what advantage of multi-threading on a concurrent queue's dequeue operation?

Comment: There may or may not be any advantage to multithreading on the dequeue operation. I would never recommend multithreading unless you know you need it or can't avoid it. The point of the `ConcurrentQueue` is just that you *can* if you need to. And the point of the exercise is just to show how multithreaded apps behave. The primary point is that we shouldn't initiate parallel or multithreaded behavior when the exact sequence of events matters. Or more broadly, to show that its behavior is predictably inconsistent.